# Does iOS control centre calls any UIApplication method.?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Control centre calls AppDelegate

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {    
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

}
```

these two method, But which UIViewController method is called

Comment: This is related to the Application delegation not with the View controllers.

Comment: Do you want to perform any action in any particular view controller when the app goes background or become active? If so, you can add notification for these events in the desired view controller ad handle accordingly.

Comment: Please refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359186/how-to-tell-the-active-view-controller-when-applicationdidbecomeactive-is-called
 May be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

When any interruption will come in application it will call

```
(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

method. And when user come back to app or interruption removed then it will call

```
(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

For example, if any incoming call come or user open notifications from sliding down or control centre.